# A inequality about analytic Function $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$, $f(z)=z+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty a_nz^n$ is analytic on $D$.  show that
$$|f(z)|\geq \dfrac{|z|(1-2|z|)}{1-|z|} \qquad |z|<1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true without further conditions.  For any $z \ne 0$, you could adjust $a_2$ to make $f(z)$ be anything you want.

Comment: sorry! I read on a  famous  inequality  book . you are right. thanks